# sub will not loop through second if statement vba

Tags: vba, excel

Really hope someone out there can help me. So i have the following code. The independent codes work fine by themself, but when executing the script, it only loops through the first condition. What i want it to do is to loop through all the code, each time. I think it's a small thing I am missing, but i can't seem to find a solution.

```
Sub Copypre()
Dim i As Integer
Dim n As Integer

 For i = 2 To 10

'Checks the number of entries in the "Pre" table, to make sure that there are no spaces between the lines

 On Error Resume Next
    n = Worksheets("Pre").Range("A2:A6000").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count
        If n = Null Then
            n = i

'Goes through the different sheets to find all "pre" values and paste them in the "Pre" sheet

    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("273").Range("A" & i).Value = "Pre" Then

        Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 3)).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("Pre").Select
        Range("A" & n).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Sheets("2736").Select

                 End If
            End If
         Next i
    End Sub
```

Comment: It isn't clear on whether the source worksheet is named *273* or *2736*.

Comment: It's hard to figure out what your problem is but you definitely have some bad code with `If n = null`. `n` is defined as an integer and cannot be null. You should change your test to `If n = 0`. Maybe this will fix your problem.

Comment: Remove `On Error Resume Next`... Do you get any errors? And `If n = Null Then` should be `n = 0`?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues with your code, but the main issue may be that `If n = Null` will never be true since an integer cannot be `Null`. You could change this to `If n = 0`.

**A couple of things to consider:**

**Error handling:** Always go back to normal error handling with `On Error GoTo 0` as soon as possible. This way you would have known (assuming that there is no sheet `"2736"` in your workbook) that your code is trying to select a sheet that does not exist.

**Range argument:** Be carefull when not specifying the sheet when using the `Range` (and `Cells`) argument. When you switch back and fourth between different sheets that you select, there is a change that you may loose track of what sheet the `Range` is returning data from. Consider declaring each worksheet and then copy your ranges like:

```
Dim w273 As Worksheet
Set w273 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("273")
w273.Range(w273.Cells(i, 1), w273.Cells(i, 3)).Copy
```

Answer (score 0):

Loops can quickly consume time with long columns of data and I suspect that your code was heavily redacted. Try this alternate method of block copying across to the destination worksheet.

```
Sub Copypre()
    With Sheets("273").Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
        .AutoFilter
        .Columns(1).AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="=Pre"
        If CBool(Application.Subtotal(103, .Offset(1, 0))) Then
            .Offset(1, 0).Resize(, 3).Copy _
              Destination:=Sheets("Pre").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        End If
        .AutoFilter
    End With
End Sub
```

All that can get accomplished without a single variable declaration.

*Addendum:*

As to your original question, the whole `if "pre"/copy/paste` section is nested within the `if n = Null` so it can only be reached if `n = Null` is true. If there are no `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)`to count, *n* will be assigned its default value (e.g. *0*). *Zero* is not equal to *Null* so that condition is never met. To check your code, add the following line.

```
On Error Resume Next
n = Worksheets("Pre").Range("A2:A6000").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count
Debug.Print "n is " & n
```

After running it, open the *Immediate* window with `Ctrl+G`. If there are no non-formula values in Pre!A2:A6000 you should see `n is 0`.

Comment: @pnuts = Yes, there is some ambiguity with the worksheet names. I've inferred that it was nothing more than a typo but I could be very wrong on that point.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks allot for all the advices. The null trick worked! I am totally new to VBA so it's nice to get some tips and tricks from experts. I will try to make the code more simple as Jeeped mentioned, as this is not very elegant. In regards to the sheets, i can totally understand the confusion, i have fixed that also. It works now and looks like this:

```
Sub Copypre()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim n As Integer

    For i = 2 To 5000
        ' Checks the number of entries in the "Pre" table, to make sure that there are no spaces between the lines

        On Error Resume Next
        n = Worksheets("Pre").Range("A2:A6000").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count

        ' Goes through the different sheets to find all pre values and paste them in the "Pre" sheet
        If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("2736").Range("A" & i).Value = "Pre" Then

            Sheets("2736").Select
            Sheets("2736").Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 3)).Select
            Selection.Copy
            Sheets("Pre").Select
            Range("A" & (n + 2)).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            Sheets("2736").Select

            Sheets("2736").Select
            Range(Cells(i, 5), Cells(i, 6)).Select
            Selection.Copy
            Sheets("Pre").Select
            Range("E" & (n + 2)).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            Sheets("2736").Select

        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```